# Using Sed to remove first part of line

Tags: regex, sed

Trying to remove the date/time part from each line of a log file with sed.
Log file eg:

```
2017-10-26 09:58:57: {..1.}
2017-10-26 09:58:58: {..2.}
```

But this:

```
cat log.log | sed "s/^.+?(?={)//g"
```

Does not work, the line is printed as is rather than with the date part removed.

Comment: for given sample, you can also use `cut -d' ' -f3- log.log`

Comment: this also works, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use lookaheads (`(?={)` in your pattern) and lazy quantifiers (`+?`) in *sed* patterns.

Use

```
sed 's/^[^{]*//'
```

where `^[^{]*` matches start of a line (`^`) and then `[^{]*` matches 0 or more characters other than `{`.

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2iDhsd)